# How do I get this wickerling?

Tags: yokus-island-express

I have one wickerling left and it's directly near me but I don't find out how to activate it.

I'm here on the map:

[image: Map]

[image: Wickerling near me]

I have tried whistling and using slugs. Do I need a specific ball color here?

It's quite hard to find answers in the Internet, because all the question titles are almost the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out: there's a hidden path from below.

[image: Get the wickerling]